# Hard reset of a single file which has been commited in git?

Tags: git, github

Hi I can do hard reset of a file whose changes have not been staged and is currently in working directory by

git checkout HEAD -- my-file.txt

as mentioned here [Hard reset of a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147270/hard-reset-of-a-single-file).

But my question is how to reset a single file to the previous head not all other files when it is commited and also if it is pushed in the remote.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- my-file.txt
```

will reset a file to the state it was in one commit before the most recent commit.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but try to remove the commit which you want with "git rebase -i" command.