# How to reset local file to the most recent commit on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, editing

I foolishly tinkered with my local file on my comp and realized I made too many edits which has ruined the application, therefore I want to start fresh all over again. The problem is, is that I can't recall all of the changes I made to manually return it to its original state. How do I take my most recent commit from my Repo, and use that to replace everything on my local file so that it can be in the exact same state before I began editing?

Comment: you need `git reset --hard <last good SHA>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard reset of a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147270/hard-reset-of-a-single-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need update your local code to the commit or branch that you want.

```
git fetch origin
git fetch origin branchOrCommitId
git reset --hard FETCH HEAD
```

Then if you want, you could create a new local branch to work in it.

```
git checkout -b nameBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back using `log` or `reflog`.

if you want to go back to specific commit.
Run in your terminal
`git log`

you will see a list having all the commits. Copy commit's hashcode where you want to revert back (min. 6 digits from the left)
and then run 
`git reset --hard hashcode` (e.g `hashcode = 6e3969`)

PS: Use can `reflog` instead of `log` to go back to your activities as well as commits.

If you are newbie then do all these commands after switching to new branch.

`git checkout -b new_branch`.

In the new branch you can do anything without any fear. If things goes fine then checkout to your original branch and do the same what you have done in `new_branch`.
If anything goes wrong. Simply delete the `new_branch`. again come to your original branch and checkout to a different branch.

Comment: This looks very useful, but as this answer is 3+ years old, I decided to double-check it & verify the syntax on the `hashcode = ...` argument. Looking in `man git-reset` I don't see a reference to a `hashcode` argument. Have I missed something?

Comment: It still works. Heer hashcode meant  `commit ID` in case of `git log`, `8 digit reference id` in case of `git reflog`. 
Do Checkout `man git-reflog`, `man git-log` and `man git-reset` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To exaclty get the most recent version from github, do:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <ruined-file-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

git fetch origin master
git reset —hard FETCH_head
git clean -df

This is what ended up working for me. Thanks for all the recommendations.