# How to get older version of a file in git

Tags: git, git-revert

Suppose my last commit includes 6 files A, B, C, D, E, F. Now I only want to revert changes of only file B.

I have committed my whole project in git. My commit id is `41e6150`. There are many files in my commit after the last commit but I want to only revert changes of specific file say X. how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard reset of a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147270/hard-reset-of-a-single-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your best option is to checkout the old version of that file and then create a new commit:

Suppose your old commit was `1a2b3c`:

```
git checkout 1a2b3c -- fileX
```

Now you have a new status where all files are up to date but `fileX` is as it was at `1a2b3c`. Just create a new commit and you've done.

Comment: kindly need bit more help . how to make new commit .?

Comment: Well, that's basic git... anyway `git add fileX`, then `git commit -m "commit message here"`

Comment: and also git push command after git commit -m "commit message here" or not ?

Comment: Do so if you want to publish everything on a server... Anyway I think you really need to follow some kind of guide, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide