# Reset one file from many already pushed in git

Tags: git

ALL,

I'm trying to resolve a following situation.

I am developing a program whose code is on Git. At one point of time I needed to update the code on Mac. The pull failed because there was an un-committed changes. One of the file which was un-committed was the Xcode file.

I tried to commit the file and pull again, but unfortunately I got a conflict. I tried to resolve the conflict with the vi and editing by hand, but I guess the Xcode internal files are not meant to be edited by hand.

Now I can go back and checkout the last known commit which will obviously won't have a latest source.

So after I do:

```
git checkout <last_known_commit>
```

what do I do in order to just bring the soure code in?

Or maybe I can reset the file from the master?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Hard reset of a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147270/hard-reset-of-a-single-file).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, this is not the answer I'm looking for. As I said the file in question was already committed and pushed to remote along with other {source} files. The link you referenced talks about non-committed file. Thank you, though.

Comment: I disagree, and the link I gave in fact does explain how to checkout a version of a single file from some other commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment yet, so here my thoughts:
As usually in git, you have many options to resolve an issue. The quick fix would be  [reset/revert your file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git?rq=1) and push that. Since you pushed your code already, that will be visible in the repo for others, but it will work. A more elegant, yet more complex, solution was presented by @argo.

A note for your Xcode IDE file: It can make sense to insert those files into the respective [git ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) if those files are induvial for each developer. I recall adding some Xcode files in the past, but I cannot remember which. I am sure you will find recommendations online.

Comment: I just did what your linked page suggested and it worked. Thank you. Also, as a side note I did add some Xcode files to gitignore, but this file according to the Google search shuoldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the these steps:

- Checkout to the version where you did last local commit.

  `git checkout <commit id>`
- Then create a branch from there

  `git checkout -b my-branch`
- make a git remote push of that branch. Do make sure the branch is present with all your local changes in the remote server
- now do git reset hard

  `git reset --hard origin/master`

Tada you are having the remote master updated. Now perform a merge to update your local changes to the master

```
git checkout master
git merge my-branch
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the process. Can elaborate? All I need is to reset one file - Xcode project. The source code should be kept locally and remotely. And I don't see the changes to the file...