# Git reset --hard for one file?

Tags: git

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but whenever I google, I can't find an answer.  Let's say I do a `git status` and 3 files are modified.  It doesn't matter if they're staged, unstaged, or whatever.  I want to reset *one* of those files back to their HEAD state, effectively doing a `git reset --hard`, but only for that one file.  How do I do that?  I'm looking for a universal command, not a "if it's staged, do x, if it's unstaged, do y."  Does such a command exist?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7147270/1256452

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout HEAD -- <file>`

Comment: see the duplicate answer posted above as a comment.