# Git discard all changes

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

Hi folks I am new developer trying to learn.

I use git desktop where you right click on a file and select discard changes, if you don't want to add that file into commit. It revert it back to its original state.

Now I am working in terminal how can I do that in terminal?

By mistake I added some changes into a file and I don't want to keep those changes. Please help.

Please, I am not an advanced user therefore kindly keep it as simple as possible. I have not made any commit on that machine yet.

I am only interested in I googled it but could not find a simple layman'ish answer.

Comment: It may help people answer accurately if you share the commands that you executed so we know exactly where you're up to. You can use `history` in terminal to show the commands you've executed (only show us relevant commands).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hard reset of a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147270/hard-reset-of-a-single-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+discard+changes+file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file
```

The `--` is so that the filename or path cannot be inferred as a branch or remote/branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways

1. You can checkout original file

```
git checkout file_path
```

2. Stash changes and continue work

```
git stash file_path
```

3. Revert head to the previous commit

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

4. Checkout to a specific commit

```
git reset --hard commit_sha
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. I will mention the simplest of all.
It has 2 step:

> 1. Unstage the file to latest/current commit. Only required if the the changes to the file is staged.
>
>    > `git reset HEAD <file>`
> 2. Undo the file changes.
>
>    > `git checkout <file>`