# hard reset or restore a file to a different location so that it does not affect my current file

Tags: git

To [hard reset a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7147270/1772898) we do something like:

```
git checkout HEAD -- my-file.txt
```

or,

```
git restore my-file.txt
```

what if we want to restore the file to a different location or with a different name.

i mean i do not want to change my current `my-file.txt` but want to restore the previous copy of that file as `my-file-old.txt`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't use it much, but I think git stash is meant to keep your current changes somewhere to maybe use later. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-stash/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

```
git show commit_id:path/to/file > another_path/to/new_name
```

Example for your case:

```
git show HEAD:my-file.txt > /tmp/restored-file.txt
```