# How can I (simply) undo changes to a file in GIT?

Tags: git, rollback

lets say I have a file, and lets call it "A.java".

....I don't have any hash tag ids / etc... I just want to go back to the file in the state before I screwed it up .

Comment: Do you mean `master` branch? Or is your the remote repo actually called `master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout -- <filename>`

this will checkout your file to the master repository.

Check this out for more information

[Difference between "git checkout <filename>" and "git checkout -​- <filename>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561142/different-between-git-checkout-filename-and-git-checkout-filename)

Answer (score 3):

`git reset --hard` will reset all files in the repository back to their state. `git checkout A.java` will reset just that file.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -- A.java
git pull #if you need to pull changes from the remote.
```

This assumes you haven't already *tried* to pull and are in the middle of a merge.