# Meaning of Git checkout double dashes

Tags: git, git-checkout

What is the meaning of the double dashes before the file name in this git command?

```
git checkout --ours -- path/to/file.txt
git checkout --theirs -- path/to/file.txt
```

Are they mandatory? Is it equivalent to

```
git checkout --ours path/to/file.txt
git checkout --theirs path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: It's a shell expression. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: @iltempo: It's slightly different for Git.  For Git, it separates the tree from the paths, in cases where trees and paths might look the same.

Comment: Also documented in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: Duplicate of [Difference between "git checkout <filename>" and "git checkout -- <filename>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561142/difference-between-git-checkout-filename-and-git-checkout-filename)

Comment: It is a duplicate, but this duplicate is at least googleable by the query 'git double dash'.

Comment: Adding just one word to timmcliu's post to clarify his or her meaning: 'The double dash "--" means "end of command line flags" i.e. it tells the preceding command not to try to parse what comes after ***as*** command line options.'

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Suppose I have a file named `path/to/file.txt` in my Git repository, and I want to revert changes on it.

```
git checkout path/to/file.txt
```

Now suppose that the file is named `master`...

```
git checkout master
```

Whoops!  That changed branches instead.  The `--` separates the tree you want to check out from the files you want to check out.

```
git checkout -- master
```

It also helps us if some freako added a file named `-f` to our repository:

```
git checkout -f      # wrong
git checkout -- -f   # right
```

This is documented in [git-checkout: Argument Disambiguation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation).

Comment: This is true for many bash commands, not just git commands, yes?

Comment: @NHDaly: Yes, it is true.  However, a terminology note: "Bash" only has a few commands (maybe 20 or so), most commands are separate programs from Bash.  It is actually part of the POSIX standard that `--` can be used to separate options from other arguments, so you will see it on commands like `cp` and `mv` (which are not part of Bash).

Comment: Any idea why this syntax is not properly described in the `checkout` command documentation?

Comment: @TanguyP: Looks like it's described at the top of https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout to me.

Comment: @DietrichEpp In several places, it's listed like a possible parameter to the `checkout` command, but nowhere does the documentation explain what it does or why it's used...which is what ultimately brought me here.

Comment: @chris: It is actually in the docs.  In the synopsis: `git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>…​]`  The `[--]` means that `--` can be used, optionally, to separate the tree from the paths.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Correct, but having read the syntax (and the examples) before coming to Stack Overflow, I still did not understand why one would or would not want to use `--`. As someone who does not come from a linux background, it's not obvious what that does. To me, it appeared to be a syntax specific to git, with no description of its functional purpose. I think it would be better to have a short description like the other options, or at least a link to a [linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: @chris: You can always refer to the "man-pages" man page, which explains the conventions for the "synopsis" section.  Anything in the synopsis which isn't given a meaning is typically just part of the command syntax, like `--`. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html

Comment: @NHDaly only the last part, about disambiguating between options and positional arguments that happen to start with a `-` is true, in general. Using `--` to disambiguate between different types of positional arguments (eg: "tree-ish" and "paths" in the case of `git-checkout`) is pretty odd. I've never heard of anything other than git that does this.

Comment: IMO this problem only exists because checking out files and branches are separate commands.

Comment: Indeed, there's similarity between git and bash.

Answer (score 131):

The double dash "--" means "end of command line flags" i.e. it tells the preceding command not to try to parse what comes after command line options.

Comment: For clarity, in `git` it means more than this, as it also means the argument after the `--` cannot be a branch name, and by implication the argument before `--` cannot be a file path.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you would not need, since Git 2.5 (Q2 2015) a '`--`' if your argument includes wildcard (`*`)

An heuristic to help the "`git <cmd> <revs> <pathspec>`" command line convention to catch mistyped paths is to make sure all the non-rev parameters in the later part of the command line are names of the files in the working tree, but that means "[`git grep $str -- \*.c`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)" must always be disambiguated with "`--`", because nobody sane will create a file whose name literally is asterisk-dot-see.

Git 2.5 looses the heuristic to declare that **with a wildcard string the user likely meant to give us a pathspec**.

```
git checkout 'a*'
# same as
git checkout -- 'a*'
```

See [commit 28fcc0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28fcc0b71a6543fe50576efc1ac8fb4e4555b6a6) (02 May 2015) by [Duy Nguyen (`nguyenlocduy`)](https://github.com/nguyenlocduy).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 949d167](https://github.com/git/git/commit/949d16795c55ae4712aaec847d55bd2d7d050c84), 19 May 2015)</sup>

> ### [`pathspec`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28fcc0b71a6543fe50576efc1ac8fb4e4555b6a6): avoid the need of "`--`" when wildcard is used
>
> When "`--`" is lacking from the command line and a command can take both revs and paths, the idea is if an argument can be seen as both an extended SHA-1 and a path, then "`--`" is required or git refuses to continue.
>   It's currently implemented as:
>
> - (1) if an argument is rev, then it must not exist in worktree
> - (2) else, it must exist in worktree
> - (3) else, "`--`" is required.
>
> These rules work for literal paths, but when non-literal pathspec is involved, it almost always requires the user to add "`--`" because it fails (2) and (1) is really rarely met (take "`*.c`" for example, (1) is met if there is a ref named "`*.c`").
>
> This patch modifies the rules a bit by considering any valid (`*`) wildcard pathspec "exist in worktree".
>   The rules become:
>
> - (1) if an arg is a rev, then it must either exist in worktree or not be a valid wildcard pathspec.
> - (2) else, it either exists in worktree or is a wildcard pathspec
> - (3) else, "`--`" is required.
>
> With the new rules, "`--`" is not needed most of the time when wildcard pathspec is involved.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), the disambiguation logic to tell revisions and pathspec apart has been tweaked so that backslash-escaped glob special characters do not count in the "wildcards are pathspec" rule.

See [commit 39e21c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39e21c6ef5221a1dcb8a241f60d7e91d59bd6627) (25 Jan 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 341f8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/341f8a6476d1d25c3906696489d87fc381739b59), 12 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`verify_filename()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39e21c6ef5221a1dcb8a241f60d7e91d59bd6627): handle backslashes in "wildcards are pathspecs" rule
>
> <sup>Reported-by: David Burström</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> Commit [28fcc0b71a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28fcc0b71a6543fe50576efc1ac8fb4e4555b6a6) (`pathspec`: avoid the need of "`--`" when wildcard is used, 2015-05-02) allowed:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse '*.c'
> ```
>
> without the double-dash.
>
> But the rule it uses to check for wildcards actually looks for any glob special.
>   This is overly liberal, as it means that a pattern that doesn't actually do any wildcard matching, like "`a\b`", will be considered a pathspec.
>
> If you do have such a file on disk, that's presumably what you wanted.
>   But if you don't, the results are confusing: rather than say "`there's no such path a\b`", we'll quietly accept it as a pathspec which very likely matches nothing (or at least not what you intended).
>   Likewise, looking for path "`a\*b`" doesn't expand the search at all; it would only find a single entry, "`a*b`".
>
> This commit switches the rule to trigger only when glob metacharacters would expand the search, meaning both of those cases will now report an error (you can still disambiguate using "`--`", of course; we're just tightening the DWIM heuristic).

([DWIM: Do What I Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM))

> Note that we didn't test the original feature in [28fcc0b71a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28fcc0b71a6543fe50576efc1ac8fb4e4555b6a6) at all.
>   So this patch not only tests for these corner cases, but also adds a regression test for the existing behavior.