# What does the double-dash [--] option do on git reset?

Tags: git, git-reset

I've seen commands like:

```
git reset e542 -- readme.txt
```

I understand this command puts in the index the contents of the file readme.txt from commit e542. But what's the `--` option doing there?

The git reset man page lists it as optional for the first two forms but I couldn't find what it means.

```
git reset [-q] [<commit>] [--] <paths>…
git reset (--patch | -p) [<commit>] [--] [<paths>…]
```

Comment: On a sidenote: You'll find this ``--`` syntax on many other command line tools, see ``rm``, ``cp``, ``chmod``, …

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch/1192194#1192194

Comment: @VonC - Thanks. Hard to find if you do not know what to look for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of Git checkout double dashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes)

Comment: @random since this question is in the context of `reset` instead of `checkout`, arguing that it's a duplicate is a hard sell. Maybe we just need to make a canonical question for this type of thing for Git, like "What does a double-dash followed by a path mean in Git?".

Comment: See also [What does “--” (double-dash) mean? (also known as “bare double dash”)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/8132).

Comment: In the context of Git and `--` checkout and reset matter less than the double dashes. But looks eventually answered here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english/ @cup

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`--` separates branch names from file names, in case there is any ambiguity (if you have a branch and a file with the same name). If there are no ambiguities, you don't need the `--`.

Also as mentioned by Jonas Wielicki, this allows for file names that start with a `-`; these would otherwise be interpreted as command-line options.

Comment: another reason: file names which start with a ``-``.

Comment: Thanks. I imagined it could be a common pattern used in *nix commands.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it just separates the commit (which is an optional parameter) from the list of paths. If you didn't have the separator there'd be no sure fire way to distinguish if the first parameter was a path or a commit.

Comment: Somewhat incorrect. Git pretty well can do that. Commits are either branch names or commit ids or other kinds of references, all of which can be easily checked (commit ids are hexvalues, other kinds of references can be found in certain directories under ``.git``). So there is *a* way to distinguish the first parameter from a path if its meant to be a commit, but _only_ if its unambigous.

Comment: That's what I meant, but my answer didn't properly capture that.