# How do I reset all deleted files

Tags: git

I have a working folder with many file changes and many deleted files.
I want to reset all the deleted files to the current HEAD, and leave any
modified files alone.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following script might do the job though it is not a **pure git solution**.

```
 git status -s | awk '{if($1=="D") { print $2 }}' | xargs git checkout --
```

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -- <deleted_file_name>` should solve your problem. You can give multiple file names as arguments to that command.

Answer (score 1):

```
git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --
```

this assumes that with "reset" you mean restore or undelete the file. because "reset" is another git concept which is related in some obscure ways. more on that later

explanation:

`git ls-files -d` will list all files that are deleted. note it will only list unstaged files. this is related to the "reset". more on that later.

`git checkout` will take the files from the current HEAD and write them in the working copy. in other words it will restore/undelete those files.

the double dash `--` is a safeguard against funny filenames starting with dash and name collisions with branches. see here for more info: [Meaning of Git checkout double dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes)

`xargs` will collect the filenames from the first part and execute the second part with the collected filenames as argument.

so if the first part looks like this

```
$ git ls-files -d
file1
file2
```

the second part after `xargs` will be this

```
git checkout -- file1 file2
```

`xargs` is not part of git but a common command line tool.

---

note about space in filename:

this command, like all involving `xargs`, will break if the files have spaces in the name.

to accomodate for space in names do like this:

```
git ls-files -d -z | xargs -0 git checkout --
                ^^         ^^
```

---

note about staging and "reset"

git has this concept called staging. it is quite powerfull but rarely needed in day to day work with git. if you commonly use `git commit -a` then you are staging implicitly.

staging is typically done using `git add`. unstaging using `git reset`. some commands like `git rm` will delete and stage automatically. a normal `rm` will only delete but not stage.

note "reset" does not do "undelete". it only does "unstage". depending on how you deleted the file you will need to unstage them first.

observe:

```
$ ls
file1  file2 file3
```

we have three files.

```
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

nothing is changed. also nothing is staged.

now we delete a file using normal `rm` and `git rm`

```
$ rm file2

$ git rm file3
rm 'file3'
```

check status

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:   file3
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:   file2
#
```

the verbose variant of git status says as it is. file3 deleted and staged ready to be commited. file2 deleted but not staged. a `git commit` at this point will only commit file3. leaving file2 unchanged in the commit but still deleted in the working copy.

now let us "reset" those deleted files

```
$ git ls-files -d
file2
```

`git ls-files -d` will only list all files that are deleted but not staged.

```
$ git checkout -- file2
```

file2 is now restored/undeleted in the working copy.

```
$ git checkout -- file3
error: pathspec 'file3' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

trying to restore file3 will give a very missleading error message.

```
$ git reset
Unstaged changes after reset:
D   file3
```

file3 is now unstaged

```
$ git checkout -- file3
```

file3 is now restored in the working copy

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

---

note

newer git introduced a `git restore` command. it replaces `git reset` when all you want is to restore/undelete a file. this is perhaps safer because `git reset` can also change commit history.

see this question and answer for more info: [What is `git restore` and how is it different from `git reset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003030/what-is-git-restore-and-how-is-it-different-from-git-reset)

---

data loss warning

if you do an unconditional `git reset` you will lose all information about which files and which changes are staged and which are not.

you will not lose the actual code changes as those will still be in the working copy. but if you just worked hard separating a merge conflict, and not commited yet, then you might want to think twice before a `git reset`.

explaining this is a bit out of scope for this question and answer. i assume that when you are asking about restoring files from HEAD then you will not have been working with a complicated staging. so a `git reset` is safe to do for you.