# How to delete a file with prefix ":" in git

Tags: git

I create a file named ":w" with unknown reason. And I cannot delete this file using "git rm". Now I wonder how to delete this file in the branch.

Comment: Was it committed? Or is it just there and not yet added? What OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to escape the filename and it should work.

```
git rm  '\:w'
```

or delete the file in the filesystem and commit

```
rm ./?w
git commit -v -a
```

Comment: thanks, I have deleted the file successfully using your method.

Comment: You could also use `git rm -- :w` -- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13321458/720999).

Answer (score 1):

From [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> *:*, e.g. *HEAD:README*, *:README*, *master:./README*
>
> > A suffix `:` followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon. `:path` (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case of the syntax described next: content recorded in the index at the given path. A
> >     path starting with `./` or `../` is relative to the current working directory. The given path will be converted to be relative to the working tree’s root directory. This is most useful to address a blob or tree from a commit or tree that has the same tree structure as the working tree.

Therefore, the colon is treated as a special character, and not treated literally.

Try prefixing the path with `./`.

```
$ ls
:w
$ git rm :w
fatal: pathspec ':w' did not match any files
$ git rm ./:w
rm ':w'
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, I have solved the problem successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and if you do

```
$ git rm ./:w
```

It will work