# Git show <commit> and get diff for a file subset

Tags: git, filter, git-diff, git-show

I am looking for a solution to get the difference of a commit using `git show <commit>` command.

Usually I make:

```
$> git show 12f00d
```

And as expected, I get all diff for all files modified in the given commit.

Now I have a big commit (many files changed/moved) after a refactoring and I just need to know what changed in all the `xml` files recursively in this commit.
I have plenty of .java, .xsl, .properties files and only few .xml files.

I tried the following commands without success:

```
$> git show 12f00d -L 0,0:*.xml 
    > incorrect syntax

$> git show 12f00d *.xml 
    > no result

$> git show 12f00d **/*.xml 
    > Return the root pom.xml but not recursively

$> git show 12f00d **/**.xml 
    > Return the root pom.xml but not recursively

$> git show 12f00d -- *.xml 
    > no result

$> git show 12f00d -- **/*.xml 
    > Return the root pom.xml but not recursively

$> git show 12f00d -- **/**.xml 
    > Return the root pom.xml but not recursively
```

I tried the same options with the command `git diff <commit>`.

I use the Git version 1.8.4 under Linux CentOS (bash terminal).

Do you know if such filter is possible with git (perhaps another command)

Comment: Are you invoking `git show` from the repository's root directory or from a subdirectory?

Comment: I have a multimodule (maven) project, and I execute the command from the parent project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`git show 12f00d '*.xml'`

Comment: Your solution does not work on my machine (Centos 6.5) but if I use now: `git show 12f00d -- '*.xml'` it works as expected.

Comment: It would be better to explain why we have to put single quotes as I did not find anything related to this in the documentation.

Comment: Here's explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: This just explain the usage of `--` but not why to wrap the last parameter with single quote.

Comment: It means that globbing will be done by git, not by your shell.