# Can git prompt me for each file on rebase?

Tags: git, merge, projects

I recently ran into this on a web project:

```
git branch new-feature
git checkout new-feature
```

*hack hack hack...*

**"Bossman: hey, there's a bug in master that needs fixing, pronto!"**

```
git commit -a -m "Partially completed migration changes"
git checkout master
git branch bugfix
git checkout bugfix
```

*hack hack hack...*
*test test test...*

**"OK, fixed!"**

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix
```

Onto completing the feature, but let's not reintroduce the bug...

```
git checkout new-feature
git rebase master

First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: some commit info
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
...
Auto-merging /some/buggy/file
CONFLICT (content): /some/buggy/file
Auto-merging /some/buggy/file
CONFLICT (content): /some/buggy/file2
Auto-merging /some/buggy/file
CONFLICT (content): /some/buggy/file3
...
```

If I happen to **know** that specific files are irrelevant to the new feature, how do I interactively force files to copy from the rebase source?

Is there a way to tell `git` to prompt me with something like:

```
copy /some/buggy/file master? y/n
copy /some/buggy/file2 master? y/n
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase consists of repeated `git cherry-pick` operations (or one single en-masse pick in some cases, but that amounts to the same thing): it takes all the commits selected by your rebase specification (basically `<upstream>..HEAD`) and copies those to new commits with the new chain grown on the `--onto` argument (which defaults to the tip of your `<upstream>` argument).

Doing the cherry-picking requires a small change of perspective: rebase starts by checking out an anonymous (detached HEAD) branch at the `--onto` point, and then iterates through the commit-IDs it saved away earlier from the `<upstream>..HEAD` before it detached HEAD.  It's these cherry-pick steps that hit the merge conflict(s) (which is why you often have to solve the merge conflicts repeatedly, once for each commit being cherry-picked).

This means that to answer your question we may want to look at [the `git cherry-pick` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) in addition to the `git rebase` documentation.  There, we find:

> When it is not obvious how to apply a change, the following happens:
>
> 1. The current branch and `HEAD` pointer stay at the last commit successfully made.
> 2. The `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` ref is set to point at the commit that introduced the change that is difficult to apply.

This means that in this state, we can use either `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file` (the `--` is not actually required here, but is [a good habit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561160/1256452)) or `git checkout CHERRY_PICK_HEAD -- path/to/file`.

Since we're now cherry-picking, not rebasing (the rebase *is* still going on, we're just in the cherry-pick *phase* at this point), `HEAD` refers to the most recent successful commit.  If the conflict is at the very first commit, `HEAD` refers to the same commit as `master` in your particular example, while `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` refers to the commit being copied from the original `new-feature` branch.  If the conflict is a bit further along, `HEAD` refers to one of the new commits that has been grown on the anonymous branch leading into the future from (again, using your example) `master`.  In either case that's the one you actually want, here.

(Side note: if you know that you didn't touch the file, it's going to be the same, in this case, in both the `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` commit *and* the `master` commit, so you can use `git checkout master -- path/to/file` instead, which is easier to type.  However, this assumes that you're rebasing onto the tip of `master`, while using the name `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` makes this independent of the target commit.)

Once the cherry-picking phase is done, `git rebase` takes over again and completes the rebase by changing the rebased branch name—in this case, `new-feature`—to point to the tip-most commit on the new anonymous branch.  The old (pre-rebase) branch tip, from before all this cherry-picking, remains in the reflog for `new-feature` (as `new-feature@{1}` or any of the other ways to name it).  It's also available in `ORIG_HEAD` at this point, until you run something that overwrites `ORIG_HEAD` (various git commands, including `git am`, `git merge`, and `git reset`, also write to `ORIG_HEAD`).  This is particularly handy if you accidentally goof up the rebase.